# How do you use constraints with Armatures?

Tags: bones, constraints

I was wondering how to use constraints with an armature, i.e. have an object copy the rotation/location of a bone, or a bone copy the rotation/location of an object. How exactly would I do this?

Comment: Select a bone, select an object, press `P`

Comment: Thats triggering the paint action.

Comment: You mean how to use *Weight Paint* features? You can edit your question after posting.

Comment: no i mean bone parenting constraints

Comment: You can use an armature as the target object of a constraint.

Comment: Sorry but can you walk me through it?

Comment: I can post an answer with a GIF

Comment: Added an answer and edited your question to try and make it clearer, feel free to comment on my answer with any further questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use armature in *Constraint* parentings very easily, select the object you wan the bone to influence, add the desired constraint, and then select the proper armature.

[image: Copy Armature Rot]

You can also select the individual bone within an *Armature* object within the *Constraint* settings.

[image: Select Armature Bone]

Not only that, you can also influence a bone's rotation via constraints:

[image: Copy Object Rot]

Comment: Its still not working properly, its pulling nearby fingers :(

Comment: Even if I move the bone up it still pulls the bones

Comment: Whoa, what about fingers? If they are seperate objects, then this is what you want. Otherwise you need to use the *Vertex Group* option.

Comment: vertex group? what tab is that in?

Comment: The constraint tab, it shows up in the GIF (under the object). I think you should accept the answer for this question and head back over to the previous one for these specifics. Duplicate questions are frowned upon, and so specifics for that question probably shouldn't be dug into in the general question.

Comment: But i don't see the option

Comment: I'll add it, just a minute . . .

Comment: Hmm . . . Bones can copy Rot/Loc of vertices, but not the other way around. You need to weight paint I think. The only other way is to parent Hook objects to the bones . . . I'll add that instead, maybe tomorrow