# How do I copy transform of a bone to an object?

Tags: bones, transforms

I can translate an object to the position of a bone with snap menu. But I would also like to give the object the same orientation as the bone. Is there a way to do this (without using a script)?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/25948/how-do-you-use-constraints-with-armatures

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks for the link but I don't want to copy the transform through a constraint. I want to apply rotation and translation of a bone to an object, basically modifying its matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use constraints**

[How do you use constraints with Armatures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/25948/how-do-you-use-constraints-with-armatures)

[image]

In 2.8 can add a constraint, tweak the settings to suit, then hit the ***Disable and Keep Transform*** button to RHS of influence slider.

Remove constraint and it still has the transform.

As a script, in pose mode, Suzanne has default XYZ Euler rotation mode

```
>>> monkey = C.scene.objects['Suzanne']
>>> C.active_pose_bone
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones["Bone"]

>>> M = C.object.matrix_world @ C.active_pose_bone.matrix
>>> monkey.rotation_euler = M.to_euler()
```

Comment: Hey thanks this is a great tip. Do you know if it is possible to keep the transform from constraints in 2.79?

Comment: Equivalent of Keyframe visual then remove keyframes. Or in console `M = C.object.matrix_world.copy()` remove constraint reset matrix world.

Comment: Awesome thanks very much @batFINGER, complete forgot that you can apply visual transform!